# Buscar último registro de um grupo distinto

Tags: mysql, sql-select, distinct

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno sistema de controle de vacinas e estou com uma dificuldade em executar um select.

Tenho um registro de cachorros, outro de tipos de vacinas e um terceiro de vacina por cachorro, onde agrupo o id do cachorro, o id do tipo da vacina (v10, antirabica, antipulgas, etc), a data da aplicação e a data da proxima aplicação.

Estou tentando buscar nesse registro de vacina por cachorro apenas a mais recente aplicação por agrupamento de cachorro e tipo, por exemplo:

```
Cachorro  Vacina  DtAplicação  DtProxima
1         1       10/03/16     10/03/17
1         1       10/03/15     10/03/16
1         2       10/03/16     10/03/17
2         1       10/03/16     10/03/17
2         2       10/03/16     10/03/17
```

Nesse exemplo acima, preciso que seja exibido todos os registros, exceto o segundo (pois se trata de uma aplicação já reforçada do mesmo tipo para o mesmo cachorro).

Segue ainda um exemplo do que estou tentando fazer para pegar as vacinas a serem aplicadas na semana atual, mas que não está filtrando corretamente:

```
SELECT c.nome, cv.vacinaoid, max(cv.proxima) FROM bicho_cachorro c 
INNER JOIN bicho_cachorro_vacina cv ON c.id = cv.cachorrooid 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR( cv.proxima ) = WEEKOFYEAR( NOW() ) 
group by 1, 2 order by 3
```

Como posso fazer essa busca? Tentei fazer um `distinct` de `c.nome` e `cv.vacionaoid`, mas não consegui fazer dos dois campos juntos.

Comment: Qual é a regra para os registros que não devem ser mostrados?

Comment: Por exemplo: o cachorro 1 tomou a vacina 1 no ano passado e nesse, entao vai ter duas entradas com os dois primeiros campos 1, porém com datas de aplicação e reforço diferentes. Eu preciso que sejam exibidas apenas o mais recente de aplicação de cada grupo. Um registro do cachorro 1 com a vacina 1, outro do cachorro 1 com a vacina 2, outro do cachorro 2 com a vacina 1, outro do cachorro 2 com a vacina 2 e assim por diante, sempre mantendo a última aplicação exibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz uma solução porém, só tenho como testar no SQL Server. Usei o conceito de subqueries, onde a query interna seleciona a última data de cada grupo e a query externa faz o join com os outros campos. Usei os mesmos nomes de campos que você usou no exemplo.

```
select vacinas.* from vacinas inner join
(
    select cachorro, vacina, MAX(DtAplicação) as DtAplicação from vacinas group by cachorro, vacina
)T
ON vacinas.cachorro = T.cachorro AND vacinas.vacina=T.vacina AND vacinas.DtAplicação=T.DtAplicação
ORDER BY cachorro, vacina
```

para selecionar as vacinas da semana é mais fácil

```
select * from vacinas where Datepart(WK, DtAplicação) = Datepart(WK, GETDATE())
```

você terá que trocar a função que obtém a semana, no meu caso usei a função do SQL Server. A função do MySql é WEEK ([documentação aqui](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php))

Espero que ajude.